# Linear independence and point wise exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Suppose I have a set V of n vectors of length n. What are the some sufficient conditions such that the exponential function applied element wise to the vectors generates a set of vectors V' that are linearly independent?

It is clear that if the vectors can be stacked to form a positive definite matrix, the Schur product theorem implies linear independence of the resulting vectors. But I am looking for more straightforward conditions.

Comment: “Exponential function applied element-wise”? Explain.

Comment: Presumably OP is talking about the map $F:(v_1,\cdots,v_n)\mapsto (e^{v_1},\dots, e^{v_n})$. Are the vectors assumed to be complex or real?

Comment: Given a vector with elements (x_1,....,x_n) the vector x'=(exp(x_1),...,exp(x_n))

Comment: You can assume only real vectors.

Comment: Here are some properties of elementwise exponential applied to a matrix (such as the matrix with your vectors as columns, for instance) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594750/properties-of-the-per-element-exponential-hadamard-exponential-for-matrices

Comment: @whpowell96 thanks! I have seen that post which is partly why I mentioned the final part that I know positive definite when stacked is one sufficient condition. But I think there are more natural and much weaker conditions.